# Why knowledge articles search doesn't return articles by topic name?

Tags: community, knowledge, articles, topics, network

In the [documentation article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_topics.htm&type=5) for enabling topics for knowledge articles, it is said that it is possible to classify and search knowledge articles by assigning topics.

However, if you enabled this feature and add a topic to an article and try to search by topic name, knowledge articles are not returned by topic name.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it somehow related to value of the `NetworkId` field here.

```
update new Topic(
                Id = '0TO060000001dVLGAY',
                NetworkId = '0DB06000000TSClGAO'
);
```

If we populate that field, everything will work.